# Double Counting Table Cell in Loop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below code to loop through the cells in my table which contain an input and totaling them up to display in the total column. Ultimately the #testerField will be changes to $this and fired off of a jQuery listener over the whole table.

The table structure is something like this:

Non Input Cell -> Non Input Cell -> Cell with Input (x8) -> Total Cell

For some reason, it keeps double counting (iterating over) the first cell in the loop. Why is this occurring?

```
sumFunction = function() {
    var row = $("#testerField").closest("tr");
    var lastCell = row.find("td:last");

    var total = 0;

    row.add('td:has(:input)').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).find(":input").val();
        
        if (value > 0) {
            total = Number(total) + Number(value);
        }  
    });

    lastCell.html(total);
}
```

Here is the HTML of one Table Row

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Trouble</td>
                        <td><input id="testerField" type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input type="number"/></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: I think you have multiple elements with the same id `testerField` and that is the problem. It would help if you added your rendered html table, and include how you call sumFunction()

Comment: I wish, but the field is unique

Comment: We need to see your html table in order to help you

Comment: Where is `Number()` defined?

Comment: It is a standard JavaScript function to convert string to number 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: @JoshuaAverbuch I'm more used to using `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function calcSum() {
    var row = $("#testerField").closest("tr");
    var lastCell = $("td:last", row);
    var total = 0;
    $("td > input", row).filter(function() {
      return $(this).val() > 0;
    }).each(function(i, el) {
      total += parseInt($(el).val());
    });
    lastCell.html(total);
  }

  $("table").ready(calcSum);
  $("table input").change(calcSum);
});
```

```css
table input {
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Trouble</td>
    <td><input id="testerField" type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" /></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here we iterate over each `input` in the row and only if they have a Value higher than 0.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var row = $("#testerField").closest("tr");
    var lastCell = row.find("td:last");
    $("table input").change(() => {
        var total = 0;
        $("td > input", row).each((i, el) => total += Number($(el).val()));
        lastCell.html(total);
    });
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Trouble</td>
        <td><input id="testerField" type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td><input type="number"/></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```